# Add exact space between values of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, whitespace

I have a dataframe over 483 days and each day I have 84 values. As this data has to be read in a groundwater-flow simulation software, it has also the corresponding stress period and the amount of values per day (84).

So here is an example which is really close to the real data:

```
Layer     Row    Column     Value1    Flag    Value2
-1 -- 3.INCRCH. Stress Period 1
3
1         95       1          11.602   -1       11.602
1         95       2          11.7     -1       11.7 
1         95       3          11.82    -1       11.82
-1 -- 3.INCRCH. Stress Period 2
3
1         95       1          11.405   -1       11.405
1         95       2          11.32    -1       11.32 
1         95       3          12.1     -1       12.1
```

Where the -1 in front of the string is a flag, indicating that this values should be read in and 3 is the amount of values per day, which would be 84 in the real data.

Now when I extract this dataframe with write.table(x) the output in the textfile is like this:

```
-1 -- 3.INCRCH. Stress Period 1
3
1 95 1 11.602   -1       11.602
1 95 2 11.7   -1       11.7 
1 95 3 11.82   -1       11.82
-1 -- 3.INCRCH. Stress Period 2
3
1 95 1 11.405   -1       11.405
1 95 2 11.32   -1       11.32 
1 95 3 12.1   -1       12.1
```

But the problem is, that the software is space-sensitive, so there has to be exactly the right amount of space between the numbers for every row, that the software can read in the data.

So the desired file would look like this:

```
     -1 -- 3. INCRCH. Stress Period 1
      3
      1        95         1    11.602        -1 11.602
      1        95         2      11.7        -1 11.7
      1        95         3     11.82        -1 11.82
     -1 -- 3. INCRCH. Stress Period 2
      3
      1        95         1    11.405        -1 11.405
      1        95         2     11.32        -1 11.32
      1        95         3      12.1        -1 12.1
```

So the space between the numbers has to be controlled exactly in this way in order to be read in the software. I tried some coding with sprintf('%10d%10d%10d%10.1f%10d%5.1f') but it only functions on some numbers I tried but not on my dataframe, even when I only tried to change one row. I have to extract the data with the write.table function, as the data file has to be a kind of text editor.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: does your software accept only single string text files? i dont understand why spaces are important if you are dealing with a csv.

Comment: Yes, it does only accept single string text files. In Microsoft I can do this with "Editor".  It is not a csv file I want to extract my data, but to an Editor file. And as it is an older part of an software, the space needs to  be exactly like I showed.

Comment: I solved the problem now, so no help is further needed! Here is how I done it: with the paste function I added a variable/symbol to each column and with the replace function in the editor I replaced the variables/symbols with the right amount of tabs needed to be in the right place. This is not the perfect solution, but it works, which is the most important part!